# How to left align ul in edm?

Tags: html, css, electronic-direct-mail

**HTML**

```
<ul style="padding-left:0;">
     <li>A journey in to  the digital</li>
     <li>Global thought leaders</li>
</ul>
```

HTML browser support this ul padding-left. So there is no issue in browser. But in Gmail that padding-left style not working. How to fix that issue.

Comment: Can you try `padding-left:0px` or `padding-left:0em`

Comment: For EDM, it is suggested that to use `table` to create something like `ul` or `ol`

Comment: Please explain a bit more what is happening and what you want to happen...

Comment: `ul` `li` listing with tables :- https://www.emailonacid.com/forum/viewthread/122/#847

Answer (score 0):

try Float:left or give margin-right: % or padding-right: %;

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each bullet in a table-cell using a pseudo element.

```
ul{
  display: table;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li{
  display: table-row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul.c1 {padding-left:0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="c1">
<li>A journey in to the digital</li>
<li>Global thought leaders</li>
</ul>
</body>
```